# Azure Synapse pipeline: How to move incremental updates from SQL Server into synapse for crunching numbers

Tags: sql, azure, architecture, dataflow, azure-synapse

We are working building a new data pipeline for our project and we have to move incremental updates that happen throughout the day on our SQL servers into Azure synapse for some number crunching.
We have to get updates which occur across 60+ tables ( 1-2 million updates a day ) into synapse to crunch some aggregates and statistics as they happen throughout the day.

One of the requirements is being near real time and doing a bulk import into synapse is not ideal because it takes more than 10 mins to do full compute on all data.

I have been reading about CDC feed into synapse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal and it is one possible solution.
Wondering if there are other alternatives to this or suggestions for achieving the end goal of data crunching near real time for DB updates.

Comment: Do you need to keep the historic changes?

Answer (score 0):

Change Data Capture (CDC) is the suited way to capture the changes and add to the destination location (storage/database).

Apart from that, you can also use **watermark column** to capture the changes in multiple tables in SQL Server.

> Select one column for each table in the source data store, which you
> can identify the new or updated records for every run. Normally, the
> data in this selected column (for example, last_modify_time or ID)
> keeps increasing when rows are created or updated. The maximum value
> in this column is used as a watermark.

Here is the high-level solution diagram for this approach:

[image]

Step-by-Step approach is given in this official document [Incrementally load data from multiple tables in SQL Server to Azure SQL Database using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-powershell).